# Создать два файла: срочный файл, содержащий текстовую часть исходного файла, и файл вещественных чисел

Tags: c++, ооп, visual-c++

**Дан текстовый файл. В каждом его строке первые 30 позиций отводятся под текст, а оставшаяся часть - под действительное число. Создать два файла: строчный файл, содержащий текстовую часть исходного файла, и файл вещественных чисел, содержащий числа из исходного файла (в том же порядке)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string path = "myFile.txt";

    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("myFile.txt");
    string a = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwer1234567890";
    string b = "mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewqmnbv0987654321";

    fout << a << endl;
    fout << b << endl;
    fout.close();
    }
```

Comment: "Срочный файл" — это какой?

Comment: *строчный -----

Comment: @Harry можете помочь?

Comment: Вы уже знаете про офстримы. Какие тогда трудности?

Comment: Все просто: читаете исходный файл построчно, разбиваете строку на подстроки (например используя `string::substr`) одну часть пишите в первый файл, вторую в другой. И как приведенный код связан с вопросом?

Comment: @AlexeyVesker ни зная, не шарю stack overflow. но атак спасибо)

Comment: ок спасибо @MBo